How to link programming languages to work in a systematic manner to form a single program?
When learning to program as a beginner in python or even other programming languages for that matter, we are taught how to get the text "hello, world" as the output when we run the, usually, a one-line program. But almost everything we encounter in our daily lives doesn't exist in a terminal. The font we encounter online are all so different, some look big while other look small and most are specially stylized.
How come we do that using a single programming language given that some are best for UI and others are best for utilities other than UI.
I would want to know, how do we go on to link different programs mostly written in different languages to form a single working code.
Note: I know a about HTML and that we can program in different in languages at the same time using a notebook. But I don't seem to wrap my head around this.
I did attend a python course but never across such a lesson unless it was an HTML course or about Flutter or something like that.
